# Streamlit Button not working- Facing this issue with the latest version of Streamlit 1.30.0. On earlier version the code was working fine

Tags: streamlit

1. I created an app using streamlit which takes data from the user in the form of "Field Names" and "Filed Types" (i.e. the data type of the fileds) to generate synthetic data
2. This is followed by Domain and Description.
3. Once all these options are filled, a "Generate Data" button needs to be activated. This button then triggers the backend code to generate synthetic data which is available for download in csv format.

PROBLEM:
The "Generate Data" button is not getting activated. I built this app using streamlit 1.29.0 where  everything worked just fine. I'm facing this issue only after the update to 1.30.0.

This is the code I'm using to create the block with options to add fields and field types.

```
col_manual_data_spec, col_csv_upload = st.columns([3, 2])

with col_manual_data_spec:
    st.markdown("<div class='box'>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    st.subheader('Manual Data Specification')

    if st.button('Add Field'):
        add_field()
    
    with st.form(key='manual_data_form'):
        all_fields_filled = True
        for i in range(len(st.session_state['field_names'])):
            col1, col2 = st.columns([3, 2])
            with col1:
                field_name = st.text_input(f'Field Name {i+1}', value=st.session_state['field_names'][i], key=f'field_name_{i}')
                st.session_state['field_names'][i] = field_name
                if not field_name:
                    all_fields_filled = False
            with col2:
                field_type = st.selectbox(f'Field Type {i+1}', options, index=options.index(st.session_state['field_types'][i]) if st.session_state['field_types'][i] in options else 0, key=f'field_type_{i}')
                st.session_state['field_types'][i] = field_type
                if not field_type:
                    all_fields_filled = False

        domain = st.selectbox('Domain Info (Mandatory)', [''] + domains, key='domain_info')
        description = st.text_area('Description (Mandatory)', key='description_info')
        if not domain or not description:
            all_fields_filled = False

        submit_button = st.form_submit_button('Generate Data', disabled=not all_fields_filled)
```

This is the code which generates the synthetic data.

```
if submit_button or (submit_csv_button and uploaded_file is not None):
field_names, field_types, domain, description = capture_and_validate_inputs()
# Construct the prompt and generate synthetic data
    if field_names and field_types:
        # Construct the prompt using the inputs
        prompt = construct_prompt(field_names, field_types, domain, description)

        # Generate synthetic data using OpenAI API
        synthetic_data = asyncio.run(generate_synthetic_data(prompt))
```

Everything in the code was just working fine, i updated some libraries i was using and streamlit and not sure what to change here.

Answer (score 0):

In streamlit 1.30.0, there has been a bugfix on the possibility to submit a form if submit button is disabled. See [this](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/releases/tag/1.30.0) and [this](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/7827).

So I suggest to also put the variable `all_fields_filled` in `st.session_state` to see if it makes any change, or to debug and track this variable to see if its value is what you expect.